# asp.net MVC - Is there a way to set a TimeSpan's max range in it's editor in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, timespan

I want to set a max `TimeSpan` range so that only 8AM - 8PM can be selected.

I'm using razor, so my html looks like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingEndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Which renders as

[image: Screen cap of the input box i'm talking about]

Is it possible to just set the `Html.EditorFor` so that it can only go up to 8 instead of 12? Otherwise, will I have to use the `[Range]` data annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the input type and ranges in the html attributes

```
type="time" min="08:00:00" max="20:00:00"
```

Do note that not all browsers respect these attributes.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/time

For Razor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingEndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "time", min = "08:00:00", max = "20:00:00"} })
```